# php form mail function

Tags: php, email, variables, concatenation

I am using a mail function to mail it to my email adress, but i want it to send me a message with variables in it.
(I have tried to concatenate it with concatenation point, but it doesn't seem to work, or I did not use it right)

The code:

```
<?php

$myEmail = "lol@lol.com";
$emailOnderwerp = "Contact form";
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
$mail1 = "<h1>";
$mail2 = "</h1><h2>Afzender:</h2><p>";
$mail3 = " (";
$mail4 = ")</p><h2>Bericht:</h2><p>";
$mail5 = "</p>";

mail("$myEmail","$emailOnderwerp",MESSAGE,"Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n"."From:info@aikodedoncker.donboscohalle.net");
?>
```

I know MESSAGE is not supposed to be there, it is just to make it easy to see that the message needs to be placed there.

So I want the message to be $mail1 + $onderwerp + $mail2 + $naam + $mail3 + ...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: plus signs are the JS/C++ way to concatenate. Use dots.

Comment: I used concatenation points already, I tried both dots(php) as plusses(js). The plusses are just to show the arrangement.

Comment: you're over-thinking this

Comment: what do you mean by overthinking?

Comment: *So I want the message to be $mail1 + $onderwerp + $mail2 + $naam + $mail3 +* ... surely this isn't just as simple as going `$message = $mail1 . $onderwerp . $mail2 . $naam . $mail3 . {and so on}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you're overthinking this and there are a few simpler ways to go about this.

Either by changing your whole block to: (no need for all those variables)

```
$mail = "

<h1>
</h1><h2>Afzender:</h2><p>
 (
)</p><h2>Bericht:</h2><p>
</p>

";
```

then

```
mail("$myEmail","$emailOnderwerp",$mail,...
```

But, if you wish to continue using what you have now:

You can concatenate in a few ways, such as:

```
$mail = $mail1 . "" . $mail2 . "" . $mail3 . "" . $mail4 . "" . $mail5;
```

or

```
$mail = "$mail1 $mail2 $mail3 $mail4 $mail5";
```

---

Sidenote:

You're missing a closing semi-colon for:

```
mail($myEmail,"$emailOnderwerp",$message,...")
```

which would throw a parse error, if that is your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use double quotes you can add the variables straight to your message string (although it does not read very well)

```
<?php

$myEmail = "lol@lol.com";
$emailOnderwerp = "Contact form";
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
$message = "<h1>$onderwerp</h1><h2>Afzender:</h2><p>($naam)</p><h2>Bericht</h2><p>$bericht</p>";

mail($myEmail,"$emailOnderwerp",$message,"Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n"."From:info@aikodedoncker.donboscohalle.net")
?>
```

(you may want to check the subject though.... but technically it should work)

Another option would be something like

```
$message.= "text and tags";
$message.= $variable
```

Or you could use HEREDOC syntax

```
$message=<<<ENDOFMESSAGE
<tags> and $variables
...
ENDOFMESSAGE;
```

Also you need to add double quotes before "Content-type"...

Hope it helps.